# Simulate drag and drop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to simulate a drag and drop with jquery or javascript.

I have to datatables where I want to simulate the drag and drop.

```
 <table class="dataTable table table-hover null table-cells dragDropTable table-draggable"  id='tableListViewFields' data-testid='tableListViewFields'>    
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr class="drag-cue" data-name="test" data-index="1">
             <td class="no-border-right">
                 test
             </td>
          </tr>

     </tbody>                    
</table>
```

The destination table looks the same.

So how can I simulate a drag ond drop from a row element to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution:
I now use https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext/blob/master/doc/drag-n-drop.md which has a very easy implementation of drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

To simulate dropping first row to second, you can manually trigger the drop event:

```
$( ".drag-cue:eq(1)" )
   .trigger("drop", $( $( ".drag-cue:eq(0)" ) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via simple javascript [HTML5 Drag and Drop](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) or as i did using JQuery plugin for ex. [Dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/)